# What are the positive consequences for choosing 8 S-boxes for DES vs 1 S-box for AES?

Tags: aes, algorithm-design, des

What are the positive consequences for choosing 8 S-boxes for DES vs 1 S-box for AES?

I could guess side channel resistance, but I can't find anything on it.

Comment: AES sbox is a bijection, while on DES they're not. Some attacks are based on sbox collisions.